# Fetching Json data using Ajax no data displayed

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to display Json data from URL in a table using ajax. I want the code to loop through the data and output it into a table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #Results{
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 80%;
        }
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        th, td {
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: left;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        }

        tr:hover{background-color:#f5f5f5}

    </style>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $.getJSON("URL", null,   
       function (json) {
           var tr;
           for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
               tr = $('<tr/>');
               tr.append("<td>" + json[i].data1 + "</td>");
               tr.append("<td>" + json[i].data2 + "</td>");
               tr.append("<td>" + json[i].data3 + "</td>");
               tr.append("<td>" + json[i].data4 + "</td>");
               $('result').append(tr);
           }
       })

   });
</script>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Results">

<table id="result">

    <tr>
        <th>
            data1
        </th>
        <th>
            data2
        </th>
        <th>
            data3
        </th>
        <th>
            data4
        </th>
    </tr>

</table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Jquery is loaded I have checked that, I dont see any errors in console.
But there is no output in the table at the moment.
can anyone point out where i am going wrong?

Comment: Is the URL you're making the request to the same as the site hosting the JS code? If not you are most likely being stopped by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in success callback. Your `JS` code should be like following.

```
$.getJSON("URL", null, function(json){
       var tr;
       for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
           tr = $('<tr/>');
           tr.append("<td>" + json[i].data1 + "</td>");
           tr.append("<td>" + json[i].data2 + "</td>");
           tr.append("<td>" + json[i].data3 + "</td>");
           tr.append("<td>" + json[i].data4 + "</td>");
           $('#result').append(tr);
       }
 })
```

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code.. doesnt seem to be doing anything still.

Comment: I have made the changes you specified, but unfortunately i still dont get any data results

Comment: Is your you `URL` ok?

Comment: Check in your console. What is it returning?

Comment: Nothing.. the console is empty

Comment: I found the proble :) didnt have # in #result

Comment: ok nice to here this, but if `url` is correct then console should not be empty.

Answer (score 1):

I Found the problem guys :)

```
$.getJSON("URL", function(json){
       var tr;
       for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
           tr = $('<tr/>');
           tr.append("<td>" + json[i].data1 + "</td>");
           tr.append("<td>" + json[i].data2 + "</td>");
           tr.append("<td>" + json[i].data3 + "</td>");
           tr.append("<td>" + json[i].data4 + "</td>");
           $('#result').append(tr);
       }
 })
```

was missing a # in result :D

Answer (score 0):

It should be 
     `$('#result').html(tr);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using id, you should use # for direct id, for example

```
$('#result').append(tr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it this way. I just used a sample json but

```
 var json = [ {data1:"Toyota", data2:"Dodge",data3:"Honda", data4:"Mazda" } ];

                 var Cars = [];

                Cars.push('<tr><th> data1  </th>  <th>  data2 </th>  <th>  data3  </th>  <th>  data4  </th> </tr>');
               for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                   Cars.push('<tr>');

                  Cars.push("<td>" + json[i].data1 + "</td>");
                  Cars.push("<td>" + json[i].data2 + "</td>");
                  Cars.push("<td>" + json[i].data3 + "</td>");
                  Cars.push("<td>" + json[i].data4 + "</td>");

                  Cars.push('<tr>');

               }
                $('#result').html(Cars);
```

in your html, it would be blank table like this:

```
<table id="result">



</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to logging your code..

try to log this data console.log(json[i]).
then check any data or error is display or not.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 $('result').html(tr);
```